# Finding one-third of a uniform distribution

Tags: uniform-distribution

I have a valuation of a cake (the unit interval $[0,1]$) such that $\int_0^1 v(x) dx =1$. This valuation tells me how much a value different pieces of cake (subintervals of [0,1]).

I am cutting the cake against 2 other guys. I know nothing about their valuations so it is just safe to assume they are uniform (I read somewhere that this minimizes entropy). I know the point x such that $\int_0^x v(x) dx =1/3$ and want to make a guess about the points y and z such that the same thing is true for the other two guys: the point at which they value the cake at 1/3. What would be my expectation about y and z? It is kind of obvious that it should be y=z=1/3, but maybe this is wrong? I am just not sure. More particular, I want to make inference about min(z,y). This is surely less than one third?

Comment: What do you mean by the other people's valuations being uniform? If you mean that they value every part of the cake the same, then there's no probabilistic element in the setup, and the point at which they value the cake at $\frac13$ is not only expected but certain to be $\frac13$; so I guess that's not what you mean. But then what do you mean?

Comment: Sorry for my poor explanation. What I mean is that I have no clue about the valuations of the other two players.

Comment: Then you're one step ahead of yourself in asking about $\min(z,y)$. You'd first need to define how the players' valuations are distributed. That's quite a non-trivial matter, as you can see e.g. [here](http://www.ma.huji.ac.il/raumann/pdf/On%20Choosing%20a%20Function%20at%20Random.pdf).